# xmlstarlet sel table data

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xmlstarlet

I am attempting to retrieve table rows from the following xml snippet. The path leading up to the snippet is `//html/body/div/div/div`. I need to select the table data rows where the `/table/tr/th/a@title='Music genre'`

I can select the tr row as:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//html/body/div/div/div/table/tr/th/a[@title='Music genre']" Unwritten_Law
```

I can select the data rows as:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//html/body/div/div/div/table/tr/td/a" Unwritten_Law
```

What I need to do is select only the data rows where the tr row is Music genre

```
<table class="infobox vcard plainlist" style="border-spacing:3px;width:22em">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2" style="text-align:center;font-size:125%;font-weight:bold;background-color:    #b0c4de"><span class="fn org">Unwritten Law</span></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row" style="text-align:left">Origin</th>
        <td><a href="/wiki/San_Diego,_California" title="San Diego, California" class="mw-redirect">San Diego, California</a>, U.S.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row" style="text-align:left"><a href="/wiki/Music_genre" title="Music genre">Genres</a></th>
        <td><a href="/wiki/Pop_punk" title="Pop punk">Pop punk</a>, <a href="/wiki/Punk_rock" title="Punk rock">Punk rock</a>, <a href="/wiki/Skate_punk" title="Skate punk">Skate punk</a>, <a href="/wiki/Post_grunge" title="Post grunge" class="mw-redirect">Post grunge</a>, <a href="/wiki/Alternative_rock" title="Alternative rock">Alternative rock</a>, <a href="/wiki/Melodic_hardcore" title="Melodic hardcore">Melodic hardcore</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row" style="text-align:left">Years active</th>
        <td>1990–present</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the snippet in the question:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "/table/tr[th/a/@title='Music genre']/td/a" Unwritten_Law
```

outputs

```
Pop punk, Punk rock, Skate punk, Post grunge, Alternative rock, Melodic hardcore
```

Add `/html/body/div/div/div` as needed.